# Creating Outlook rule with python win32com library

Tags: python, outlook, office365, win32com, rules

i want the script to create an outlook rule which is "to forward new coming emails whose subject contains 'verification code' to 'osam1399@gmail.com'" but i get the error that it has no 'Rules' attribute.

Following is the code:

```
    import win32com.client
    
    rec_email = 'osam1399@gmail.com'
    rule_name = 'Forward_2fa_emails'
    rule_conditions = "@SQL=urn:schemas:mailheader:subject LIKE '%verification code%'"
    rules_actions = 'forward to ' + rec_email
    
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.Application').GetNamespace('MAPI')
    inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
    
    rules = inbox.Parent.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules()
    new_rule = rules.Create(rule_name, 2)
    
    new_rule.Conditions().Subject = rule_conditions
    new_rule.Actions().ForwardTo = rules_actions`your text`
    new_rule.Enabled = True
    new_rule.save()
```

Comment: What’s the exact error text?

Comment: Does the `Save` method throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

The [MoveOrCopyRuleAction.Folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.moveorcopyruleaction.folder) property returns or sets a `Folder` object that represents the folder to which the rule moves or copies the message, not a string like it is used in your code sample.

The following code creates a new rule in Outlook according to your conditions (VBA sample code):

```
Sub CreateRule() 
    Dim colRules As Outlook.Rules 
    Dim oRule As Outlook.Rule 
    Dim colRuleActions As Outlook.RuleActions 
    Dim oMoveRuleAction As Outlook.MoveOrCopyRuleAction 
    Dim oTextCondition As Outlook.TextRuleCondition
    Dim oInbox As Outlook.Folder 
    Dim oMoveTarget As Outlook.Folder 
 
    'Specify target folder for rule move action 
    Set oInbox = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
    'Assume that target folder already exists 
    Set oMoveTarget = oInbox.Folders("Target folder") 
     
    'Get Rules from Session.DefaultStore object 
    Set colRules = Application.Session.DefaultStore.GetRules() 
     
    'Create the rule by adding a Receive Rule to Rules collection 
    Set oRule = colRules.Create("Sample rule", olRuleReceive) 
 
    'Specify the condition in a TextRuleCondition object 
    'Condition is if the message is from "Dan Wilson" 
    Set oTextCondition = oRule.Conditions.Subject
    With oTextCondition 
        .Enabled = True 
        .Text = "verification code"
    End With 
 
    'Specify the action in a MoveOrCopyRuleAction object 
    'Action is to move the message to the target folder 
    Set oMoveRuleAction = oRule.Actions.MoveToFolder 
    With oMoveRuleAction 
        .Enabled = True 
        .Folder = oMoveTarget 
    End With 
 
    'Update the server and display progress dialog 
    colRules.Save 
End Sub
```

The Outlook object model is common for all programming languages, so I hope you will find all the required properties and methods that you could use in a python script.